# How to register a service worker's scope one directory above where the service_worker.js is located

Tags: javascript, scope, service-worker

MY directories are as follows.

```
public_html/
sw/
```

The "sw/" is where I want to put all service workers, but then have those service workers with a scope to all the files in "public_html/".

**JS**

```
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw/notifications.js', { scope: '../sw/' }).then(function(reg) {
    // registration worked
    console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
};
</script>
```

How do I allow this sort of scope?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [max scope for a service worker is where it is located](https://github.com/delapuente/service-workers-101/). This means you can not register one service worker located at `/sw/` in `scope: '/public_html/'` unless you include a special header `Service-Worker-Allowed` set to the new max scope for your service worker.

Summarizing, if you can add this header when serving the service worker, set it as follows:

```
Service-Worker-Allowed: /public_html/
```

If not, you must place the sw at some location above the scope.

Comment: For any other lost soul like me looking for where or how to add this header, it needs to be added on the back end. On the web server serving the service worker file, like this person demonstrates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084718/how-exactly-add-service-worker-allowed-to-register-service-worker-scope-in-upp/49098917/

Meaning your service worker request should look like this:
https://medium.com/dev-channel/two-http-headers-related-to-service-workers-you-never-may-have-heard-of-c8862f76cc60

Answer (score 3):

Edit: As [Salva's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35415127/2014893) indicates, the max scope must be widened with [the `Service-Worker-Allowed` header](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/#service-worker-allowed) to allow the following to succeed.

---

Change the `scope` property of the registration options object (the second parameter of `navigator.serviceWorker.register()`) to the URL you would like the service worker to be scoped to. In your case, this may be `../public_html`.

```
// ...
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw/notifications.js', { scope: '../public_html/' })
// ...
```

---

That parameter will default to `./` (relative to the ServiceWorker script) if the options object is not provided, or has no `scope` property.

Also, setting a `scope` with any [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) other than the current origin [will reject the registration Promise with a `SecurityError` exception.](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#register-algorithm)

---

References:

https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#navigator-service-worker-register

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register#Parameters

Comment: This will throw an error stating the scope is outside of the allowed scope. You need to also set the header as per the other answer.

Comment: Will return the following error: The path of the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope allowed ('/scripts/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.