# Placing a workbox-build service worker in a subdirectory of the globDirectory

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, workbox-window

I am using [workbox-build](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-build) to generate a service worker. My directory structure looks something like this:

```
src/
src/a.png
src/index.html
src/Workbox/
src/Workbox/workbox-window.prod.mjs
service-worker/
service-worker/build.js
```

`build.js`, which I am running with Node.js, looks something like this:

```js
const { generateSW } = require("workbox-build");

generateSW({
    globDirectory: "../src/",
    globPatterns: ["**/*"],
    swDest: "../src/Workbox/service-worker.js",
})
```

The idea is that `build.js` should generate a service worker, which is placed in `src/Workbox`, that caches every file in `src/`.

`index.html` looks something like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module">
            import { Workbox } from "./Workbox/workbox-window.prod.mjs";
            if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) new Workbox("Workbox/service-worker.js").register();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

However, upon loading the page, I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"http://localhost:8000/src/Workbox/a.png","status":404}]
```

The issue is clear: the service worker is trying to cache a nonexistent file `src/Workbox/a.png`, rather than the file `src/a.png`. I had expected only `globDirectory` to be relevant to the cached file locations, but it seems `swDest` is also relevant. If I change `swDest` to `"../src/service-worker.js"` and make the appropriate modification to `index.html`, then all the files are precached as expected. But I would really like `service-worker.js` to be placed in the `src/Workbox` subdirectory rather than `src/`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same issue in the future, this is [not possible](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2530). The reason is that a service worker must be in the top scope due to [scoping restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358038/how-to-register-a-service-workers-scope-one-directory-above-where-the-service-w/35415127#35415127).